# FFNN help on hyperband tuning

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Im developing a time series toy problem to learn feedforward neural networks. In this case, I want to predict the temperature in Nova Dehli based on some inputs.

I developed the model but now Im trying to tune the parameters using hyperband tuning.

The problem is that I find it weird the time it is consuming. It always takes 21 seconds to run the entire code. No matter if I increase the hyperband_iterations from 1 to 100000000000 or change the factor from 3 to 3000. Always 21 seconds. And I think thats the time it takes to run the 250 epochs of the supposed "best model".

```
# Define the model for regression
def model_builder(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()

    hp_units1 = hp.Int('units1', min_value=1, max_value=500, step=1)
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=hp_units1, activation='relu', input_shape=(Xtrain_np.shape[1],)))

    hp_units2 = hp.Int('units2', min_value=1, max_value=500, step=1)
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=hp_units2, activation='relu'))

    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))

    # Tune the learning rate for the optimizer
    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e0, 1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4 ])

    # Use 'mean_squared_error' for regression task
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
                  loss='mean_squared_error',
                  metrics=['mae'])  # Mean Absolute Error is a common metric for regression

    return model

**#Tuning**
tuner = kt.Hyperband(hypermodel = model_builder,
                     objective = 'val_loss',
                     max_epochs=500,
                     factor=30,
                     hyperband_iterations=1,
                     seed=None,
                     hyperparameters=True,
                     tune_new_entries=True,
                     allow_new_entries=True,
                     max_retries_per_trial=5,
                     max_consecutive_failed_trials=5)

stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=400)

# Search for the best parameters
tuner.search(Xtrain_np, ytrain_np, epochs=400, validation_data=(Xval_np, yval_np), callbacks=[stop_early])
```

I tried to change all of the parameters in tuning like hyperband_iterations, factor and max_epochs. Nothing changes the time it takes.